# Could not find org.nodejs:x64

Tags: node.js, gradle-node-plugin

When I try to build my Frontend app I get

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':frontend:nodeDist'.
> Could not find org.nodejs:x64/node:6.17.1.
  Searched in the following locations:
      http://nodejs.org/dist/v6.17.1/ivy.xml
      http://nodejs.org/dist/v6.17.1/x64/node.exe
```

On another machine it downloads the node without issue from http://nodejs.org/dist/v6.17.1/win-x64/node.exe

Why does my machine not create the same download url with **win-x64** instead of **x64**?

my build.gradle contains:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:0.10'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.moowork.node'

node {
    version = '6.17.1'
    npmVersion = '2.10.1'
    download = true
}
```

upgrading the versions is not an option in my case

Comment: You're running a 7 year old version of a plugin that was abandoned 3 years ago, the odds of getting any support is slim and your best bet is upgrading to the community supported plugin https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin